# Terraform: Custom json properties including dots not working

Tags: json, output, terraform

I'm dealing with problems to get a specific property out of a json output from terraform.

Here is my code:

```
output "Hostname" {
  value = [
    for props in sort(vra_deployment.CentOS7VM.resources.*.properties_json) :
    jsondecode(props).Custom.VirtualMachine.Network0.Hostname
  ]
}
```

Here is snippet output from `terraform show`

```
properties_json = jsonencode(
                {
                    Custom.VirtualMachine.Network0.Hostname = "myhost.foo.bar"
                    Custom.VirtualMachine.Network0.Network  = "192.168.111.0/24"
                    VirtualMachine.Network0.Address         = "192.168.111.39"
                    VirtualMachine.Network0.SubnetMask      = "255.255.255.0"
                    account                                 = "vsan-yay"
                    address                                 = "192.168.111.39"
       ...

}
```

I can output "address" for example or even "account", but nothing that starts with "Custom", I need the hostname in my output, which is this property: Custom.VirtualMachine.Network0.Hostname

Error:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 49, in output "Hostname":
  49:     jsondecode(props).Custom.VirtualMachine.Network0.Hostname

This object does not have an attribute named "Custom".
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using dot-notation, you are saying that it has an attribute called "Custom", which has an attribute called "VirtualMachine", which has an attribute called "Network0", etc. Try using bracket notation instead:

```
... jsondecode(props)["Custom.VirtualMachine.Network0.Hostname"]
```

Dot-notation is fine until one (or more) of the attribute names contains a dot; at that point it breaks down. In fact, in a worse scenario, you could conceivably have an entry called `"one.two"` and another entry called `"one"` with a sub-attribute called `"two"` - if you use dot notation in this case, it will select the latter item, and instead of an error you'll just get an unexpected value.